# Ubuntu 16.04 Ros Kinect Installation Unmet Dependencies

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried literally every solution found on this website and beyond - no luck. Whatever I did, the installation just wouldn't work. Running this:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

always and always results with:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-kinetic-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-kinetic-perception but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-kinetic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Before someone tells:

1. Ubuntu repositories of mine do include all three which you think of. I tried other countries' repositories as well, no luck.
2. Installing qt binding also did not work. I did remove qt5 library and I am still unable to install ROS.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

```
python-catkin-pkg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.10-2
  Version table:
     0.4.8-100 500
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     0.2.10-2 1001
       1001 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
       1001 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
python-catkin-pkg-modules:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.4.8-1
  Version table:
     0.4.8-1 500
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

**EDIT2:** Even after removing the package which caused the mess, I still cannot install ROS with the standard command. I did do aptitude and this is the output:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/f1b525cf32e3e0e3e3dc7d080f97f30c

**EDIT3:** Here is the output of my list:

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   66 Okt 11 14:03 cuda-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update-2.list

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   66 Okt 11 14:03 cuda-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update-2.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   64 Okt 11 14:03 cuda-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   64 Okt 11 14:03 cuda-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   38 Okt 11 14:03 cuda-9-0-local.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   38 Okt 11 14:03 cuda-9-0-local.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Okt 11 11:55 docker.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Okt 11 11:55 docker.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Okt 11 14:03 google-chrome.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Okt 11 14:03 google-chrome.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Okt 10 15:46 isv:ownCloud:desktop.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Okt 10 15:46 isv:ownCloud:desktop.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   49 Okt 11 14:03 matrix-riot-im.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   49 Okt 11 14:03 matrix-riot-im.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  459 Okt 11 14:03 mendeleydesktop.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  459 Okt 11 14:03 mendeleydesktop.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  146 Okt 11 14:03 mystic-mirage-ubuntu-pycharm-xenial.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  146 Okt 11 14:03 mystic-mirage-ubuntu-pycharm-xenial.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Okt 10 15:43 nvidia-docker.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Okt 10 15:43 nvidia-docker.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  130 Okt 11 14:03 peterlevi-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  130 Okt 11 14:03 peterlevi-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   51 Okt 11 14:03 ros-latest.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   51 Okt 11 14:03 ros-latest.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   56 Okt 11 14:03 skype-stable.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   56 Okt 11 14:03 skype-stable.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 Okt 11 14:03 spotify.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 Okt 11 14:03 spotify.list.save
```

I had to remove universe one since it caused the priority (500 vs 1000) issue with the python-catkin-pkg. Apart from that all others are checked on the Ubuntu Software Center.

As for the `cat /etc/apt/preferences.d`, I have only one file called `allow-downgrade` with the following content:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305386/ubuntu-16.04-ros-kinect-installation-unmet-dependencies/) by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At least for `python-catkin-pkg` and `python-catkin-pkg-modules` it turned out that the OP had a `allow-downgrade` file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` that pinned the priority of all Ubuntu repositories (ie: official ones) to `1001`.

As `python-catkin-pkg` is also provided by the Ubuntu repositories (via Debian and the [UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages)), the higher priority of the Ubuntu repositories caused `apt` to only want to install the `0.2.10-2` version and not the most recent one (at this point in time: `0.4.8-100`).

Removing the `allow-downgrade` file at least resolved the `python-catkin-pkg` problem, but additional issues with `apt` then popped up.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2018-10-11**:
Yes. I'd like to also add that it's still unclear at this point what actually causes the problem, but one should acknowledge that it is clearly not a ROS problem, rather an Ubuntu problem. Thank you for effort again.